# Calculating balance Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a problem. I just wanna calc the balance of my table.

my select statement is:

```
select date, ammount, ?? as Balance 
from table 
where accountnr = 123 
order by date
```

Output should look like this:

```
Date             Ammount         Balance 
 
07/02/2016       -145.55         945.65
25/01/2016        349.45         1091.20 
11/11/2015        340.25         741.75
30/09/2015        369.10         401.50        
05/04/2015        32.40          32.40
```

I tried so long, with different ways without luck.

Comment: I really hope this is a school/homework. (If not, please tell me which bank to avoid.)

Comment: Isn't the balance the latest entry into the table?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho, true that's my mistake. I'll correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single table scan (i.e. without any joins or correlated sub-queries) with an analytical query:

```
SELECT "date",
       amount,
       SUM( amount ) OVER ( ORDER BY "date" ) AS balance
FROM   your_table;
```

If there are multiple accounts in the table then:

```
SELECT account_number,
       "date",
       amount,
       SUM( amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY account_number ORDER BY "date" ) AS balance
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: Wow... that what it!! Thank you sooo much.